# If $f: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(x)=f(2x)$ for each $x\in\Bbb{R}$ then $f$ is constant.

Tags: calculus, continuity, functional-equations

How do I prove that if $f: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$  is continuous at $0$ and $$f(x)=f(2x)$$
for each $x\in\Bbb{R}$, then $f$ is constant?

Comment: You mean "continuous *at* 0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(a)\neq f(b)$, then $f(a\,2^{-n})=f(a)$ and $f(b\,2^{-n})=f(b)$ for each $n$. By continuity, $f(0)=f(a)=f(b)$ which is a contradiction.

It is usually appreciated if you also write down your ideas or trials.

Comment: what does "$f(a\,2^{-n})$" simplify?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani $a 2^{-n}$ converges to $0$, so $f(a\,2^{-n})$ converges to $f(0)$. The same for $b$.

Comment: $2^{-n}$ simplify the values that can be inserted in the function?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani Unfortunately, I don't understand what you don't understand. If you know what is a limit, continuity and $2^{-n}$, then you should probably try to specify more in your question, where is your problem and what are your ideas, then the community could help you more.

Comment: I got it at the end:) thank you. and next time I will write down my thoughts so it will be better coordinated question.

Answer (score 2):

The functional equation implies $f\Bigl(\dfrac{x}{2}\Bigr)=f(x)$, hence $f(x)=f\Bigl(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\Bigr)$ for all $n$.